# FileReader doesn't work in Opera 12.11 for Mac?

Tags: html, opera, filereader

I tried FileReader in Opera 12.11 today and suddenly it didn't work for me. No matter what, all read methods produce an empty string. Try something as simple as:

```
<input id="file-picker" type="file" />​

...

$('#file-picker').change(function() {
    var fr = new FileReader();

    fr.onload = function() {
        console.info(this.result);        
    };

    fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

});​
```

Here is a quick [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HehZG/1/).

Huh?

**UPDATE:** It happens on Mac. I was told that it's fine on Win7.

Comment: Your given fiddle wfm on 12.10 at least, doubt it will have broken in 12.11, but will check later.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be:

```
fr.onload = function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.result)
}
```

I've always do like this. Didn't tested on Opera though

Comment: e.target and this are the same thing (FileReader instance) in specified context.

Comment: You're right about `this`, however when I actually tested it with Opera in Mac it works correctly.

Comment: Did you test it through the provided jsFiddle? Opera 12.11?